# Solve update error messages Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth

I installed a new driver for bluetooth recently on Ubuntu14.04...but it seemed that it only works once, after rebooting, it didn't work anymore...so I kind of gave up solving my bluetooth problem. The thing is recently when I run my updates, these messages kept coming up:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.videolan.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6BCA5E4DB84288D9
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am pretty sure that it came from the driver I installed for the bluetooth function, politely asking how I could reinstall the driver?

Or what are better places to solve update error message problems?

Thank you!! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically running the following should work:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6BCA5E4DB84288D9
 sudo apt-get update
```

And there are no packages for 14.04 in that [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/ppa/ubuntu/dists/), so you should remove those PPA entries from your sources files. Read [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) to know how to remove them.